# Spark Scala read CSV which has a comma in the data

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

My `CSV` file which is in a zip file has the below data,

```
"Potter, Jr",Harry,92.32,09/09/2018
 John,Williams,78,01/02/1992
```

And I read it using spark scala `csv` reader. If I use,

```
.option('quote', '"')
.option('escape', '"')
```

I will not be getting the fixed number of columns as output. For line 1, the output would be 5 and line 2 it would be 4. The desired output should return 4 columns only. Is there any way to read it as `DF` or `RDD`?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: the csv is valid one.. you should be able to read without specifying the options

Answer (score 0):

For the given input data, I was able to read the data using:

```
val input = spark.read.csv("input_file.csv")
```

This gave me a Dataframe with 4 string columns.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
  val df = spark.read.csv("in/potter.txt").toDF("fname","lname","value","dt")
  df.show()

+----------+--------+-----+----------+
|     fname|   lname|value|        dt|
+----------+--------+-----+----------+
|Potter, Jr|   Harry|92.32|09/09/2018|
|      John|Williams|   78|01/02/1992|
+----------+--------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed something, I'm not reading it as a direct 'CSV' file. It is a zip file which has multiple CSVs, I need to make all the CSVs into a one single CSV and then process.